# PSremoting remotely

Tags: session, powershell, remote-access, powershell-remoting

I made a script that open session to list of servers. The problem is that I need to run the command : "enable-Psremoting" on each of the servers manually, is anyone know a better way ? and not psexcec.

Comment: Share some code to understand the issue please

Comment: This is not on topic here. There are several methods for enabling PS remoting on machines. [In a domain, you can use group policy](http://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/) (my blog), if not, you can use configuration management if you're set up for it (puppet, chef, dsc), you could enable it during deployment with WDS or when deploying from a VM template, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the target computers Respond to WMI, you can use Lee Holmes nice script for that...

http://poshcode.org/2141